# Needs regular expression that doesn't starts with space and doesn't contain special characters in C#

Tags: c#

I tried to use this regular expression `@"^\s+[^<>.!@#%/]$"`, but it didn't help.So i need to use regular expression,that doesn't starts with space and doesn't contain special characters.

Comment: Share your code and comment what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `@"^[^\s].*[^<>.!@#%/].*"`

Comment: It works thank you for help.